# Fixing Data Types in Dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-unicode

I have imported a file using unicodecsv.DictReader but with it returning a list of file.

```
import unicodecsv

def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)
        return list(reader)

imdb_data = read_csv('tmdb-movies.csv')
imdb_data [0]
```

After that I go on to create functions to change datatypes. However, I keep getting an error message of "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Below is the code I was attempting. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
for imdb in imdb_data:
    imdb_data['popularity'] = parse_maybe_float(imdb['popularity'])
```

Comment: `read_csv` returns a `list`, so you can index it with integers, not with strings, like you're trying in `imdb_data['popularity']` - it's probably just a typo and you meant to write `imdb['popularity']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was using Jupyter Notebook incorrectly, which was causing the error. Thank you for trying to help me though.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a list with the index 'popularity', that shouldnt work (index should be a number).
It looks a lot like a typo:

```
for imdb in imdb_data:
    imdb_data['popularity'] = parse_maybe_float(imdb['popularity'])
```

The second line needs to be changed, since `imdb` is an element in `imdb_data` maybe you meant a second list instead of `imdb_data`?